# Alignment confusions in css

Tags: html, css

This is my last question with regards to the issues. I've raised another query just before this and can be found at [Border width to change as per the inner div content width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41606140/border-width-to-change-as-per-the-inner-div-content-width/41606300#41606300)

Thanks people to ride me in the correct direction.

My code is as below

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>

    <div class="panel-body chat-box-main">
        <div class="chat-box-left">Hello, Welcome!. You can ask me
            questions on Compliance Policy ..</div>
        <div class="chat-box-name-left">
            <img src="compiler-bot-static.gif"
                alt="bootstrap Chat box user image" class="img-circle"> - Bot
        </div>



        <div class="chat-box-right" id="chatbox">Hi</div>
        <div class="chat-box-name-right">
            <img src="smiley.jpg" alt="bootstrap Chat box user image"
                class="img-circle">
        </div>
        <div class="chat-box-left">Hello</div>
        <div class="chat-box-name-left">
            <img src="compiler-bot-static.gif"
                alt="bootstrap Chat box user image" class="img-circle">- Bot
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

and my CSS is

```
.hr-clas {
    border-top: 1px solid #A12EB3;
}

.chat-box-main {
    height: 400px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.chat-box-div {
    border: 2px solid #A12EB3;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A12EB3;
}

.chat-box-head {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #A12EB3;
    background-color: #B25AE5;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

.chat-box-left {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #C5C5C5;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.chat-box-left:after {
    top: 100%;
    left: 10%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-top-color: #C5C5C5;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.chat-box-name-left {
    margin-top: 1.5em;
    margin-left: 4%;
    text-align: left;
    color: #049E64;
}

.chat-box-name-left img {
    max-width: 40px;
    border: 2px solid #049E64;
}

.chat-box-right {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #C5C5C5;
    font-size: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #73AD21;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: inline-block;

    /* width: auto;
    height: auto;
    padding: 35px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #C5C5C5;
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block; */
}

.chat-box-right:after {
    top: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    right: 10%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    border-top-color: #C5C5C5;
    border-width: 15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}

.chat-box-name-right {
    color: #354EA0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    text-align: right;
}

.chat-box-name-right img {
    max-width: 40px;
    border: 2px solid #354EA0;
}

.chat-box-footer {
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Currently the issue is as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

1. Here the first block is displaying everything is correct. The first `hi` above the smiley should be on the right side. I tried using `float: right`, but it is displaying, the smiley just next to the message
2. The arrow above the robot is very left side, I want this to be placed in order as shown in the first robot content.
3. The circles are to be a bit better appealing.

Please let me know how can I get this done.

Here is a working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/2rp4978t/

Thanks

Comment: Would be more helpful if you would put the code in a snippet.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle of some sort.

Comment: @bens and techouse, apologies for missing that, added a fiddle in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Add float:right like such:

```html
.chat-box-name-right {
    color: #354EA0;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 60px;
    text-align: right;
    float:right;
}
```

This will move "Hi" to the right.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look @ https://jsfiddle.net/e62obomn/

All I have done is encased the chats in a div and used text align for the right text area.

HTML

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="chat-box-right" id="chatbox">Hi</div>
    <div class="chat-box-name-right">
        <img src="smiley.jpg" alt="bootstrap Chat box user image" class="img-circle">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.chat-box-left:after {
  top: 100%;
  left: 25px;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  border-top-color: #C5C5C5;
  border-width: 15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Friend this is awesome, but another issue is leftout. Look at The arrow below `Hello`. This should be equally aligned with the box. Can you please look into it?  Thanks Again!!!

Comment: Please see updated FIddle. I changed the .chat-box-left:after -> left from 10% to 25px. You can change it to more or less depending on where you would like the arrow.